Is it possible to consume kafka topics in salesforce
We have a requirement where SF need to act as subscriber to a kafka channel.However I did not find any native way of doing it. SF can publish the events but no documentation around subscribing the events.
I have found few paid connectors, I want to check if there is any native way to do it.

Salesforce can't subscribe to Kafka events. It can only subscribe to Platform Events. You'll need an external connector to send messages to Salesforce.

The Salesforce Connector integrates Salesforce.com with Apache Kafka® includes both a sink connector and a source connector.
https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/salesforce/current/overview.html
